# Find specific pattern from var value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i've var object with content inside of it and I want to find to array just the
text which look like following pattern

value:function()

the space between it doesnt matter ,

for example for the following text I should get an array `[dosomthing,press,click]`

```
doSomething:function()

press : function()


click: function
```

I need to get an array like

after searching the forum I found some example which doesnt work for me.
any idea how to handle it?

```
var array = (s.indexOf("/\w+:\s*:function") > -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead to match the word characters which are followed by the string `:function`

```
> s = 'doSomething:function()\npress : function()\n\nclick: function'
> s.match(/\w+(?=\s*:\s*function)/g)
[ 'doSomething', 'press', 'click' ]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                         more times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                           or more times)
  :                        ':'
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                           or more times)
  function                 'function'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thanks voted up this is great I will mark as answer,please just add some explanation on the regex.thanks!

Comment: Added according to your wish.

Comment: Thanks,one last question how should I ignore name which is start with underscore like _press:function() ...

Comment: try `\b[A-Za-z]\w*(?=\s*:\s*function)`

Comment: did you don't want to allow `_` anywhere on the name?

Comment: i've just opend new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717396/find-match-pattern-in-string-object ,please see if you can help,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you posted a malformed object. If we correct the code..

```
{
    doSomething:function() {},
    press : function(){}, 
    click: function(){}
}
```

...we can use `Object.keys()` to extract its keys, and then filter them by only methods.

```
var myObject = {
    doSomething: function(){},
    press: function(){},
    click: function(){},
    someOtherProperty: 5
};

var keys = Object.keys(myObject);

var methods = keys.filter(function(key){
    return typeof myObject[key] == 'function';
});
```

The variable `methods` will be `['doSomething', 'press', 'click']`.