# find match pattern in string object

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have string with values and I want to identify the pattern
in the string like

```
value:function()

like name:function()
or

click:function()
```

I want to ignore space and value cannot start with underscore and in addition

I have some array with word that I want to ignore like user ,address

i.e if I have the following

```
name:function()

click:function()

_press:function()

user: function()
```

the array at the end will have only `[name,click]`

I try like following as suggested by Avinash but its not working for all the conditions,
any idea?

```
str.match(/\w+(?=\s*:\s*function)/g)
```

Comment: how about this http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/13 ?

Comment: In what scenario is Avanash's solution not working?  It seems to match all the requirements you listed.

Comment: @BrentStewart he don't want to match the names which starts with `_` and he don't want to match the names `user` and `address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want something like this,

```
\b(?!address|user|_)\w+(?=\s*:\s*function)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/13)

```
> s = 'name:function()\n\nclick:function()\n\n_press : function()\n\nuser: function'
> s.match(/\b(?!address|user|_)\w+(?=\s*:\s*function)/g)
[ 'name', 'click' ]
```

Comment: Thanks,but when I try it on match match.(\b(?!address|user|_)\w+(?=\s*:\s*function) I got error unexpected token illegal,any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot ,btw what is the g at the end ?

Comment: `g` = global flag. It helps to do a global match. Otherwise the match wouldn't go for the next match. Just try the regex without `g` flag, you could see the difference.